# Xtext DSL: boolean rule with 2 different string

Tags: grammar, dsl, xtext, ecore

Currently I have problem in defining a boolean variable :

I have a class with a boolean variable:

```
Pet:
   isFeline ?= 'cat' | isFeline ?= 'dog' ;
```

However this result in Pet returning with 'cat'/'dog' as true. Is there anyway to define DSL: 'cat' as true and 'dog' as false ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
Pet:
    {Pet} (isFeline?='cat' | 'dog');
```

Normally it should do what you want!